# Django, admin panel, dependence of the values of one ForeignKey field available for selection on the value selected in another ForeignKey field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have models:

models.py

```
class CommentCollection(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Comment(models.Model):
      comments_collection = models.ForeignKey(CommentCollection, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      reply_to = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='replies', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      text = models.TextField()
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Published')
```

<admin.py>

```
@admin.register(CommentCollection)
class CommentCollectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ['id', 'name']
```

How to make it so that:
When adding a new comment via the admin panel, after filling in the "comments_collection" field (selection from the CommentCollection model), only those comments that belong to the same collection of comments are displayed in the reply_to field for selection.

```
@admin.register(Comment)
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ('comments_collection', 'user', 'created', 'is_public')
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code to your `CommentAdmin`. when you do modification, there is no need to JS, but for adding a new option, you need to pass data from FE to BE. I'm not sure if add part will work, but you can get an idea...

```py
def render_change_form(self, request, context, add, change, form_url, obj):
    if add:
        collection_id = (
            request.GET.get("comment_collection")
            if request.GET.get("comment_collection")
            else -1
        )
    if change:
        collection_id = obj.comments_collection.id
    reply_to_qs = context["adminform"].form.fields["reply_to"].queryset

    context["adminform"].form.fields["reply_to"].queryset = reply_to_qs.filter(
        comments_collection_id=collection_id
    )
    return super().render_change_form(request, context, add, change, form_url, obj)
```

create a file at this location for more detail refer to django doc.

`project/app_name/templates/admin/app_name/change_form.html`

```html
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load admin_urls static admin_modify %}  
{% block footer %}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    commentSelection = document.getElementById("id_comments_collection")
    commentSelection.onchange = function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "{% url 'admin:app_name_comment_add' %}",
                data: {"comment_collection": commentSelection.value},
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(commentSelection.value);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }
            })
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is what we need and it almost works.  
In `context["adminform"].form.fields["reply_to"].query` set records the value that is needed. 
 But the dropdownlist "Reply to" on the form itself is not updated. It is updated only once when an existing comment is opened or when a new comment is created.

Comment: When I create a new comment dropdownlists "Comments collection" is empty and "Reply to" is also empty as it should be. And when I select a value in the "Comments collection", render_change_form is triggered using debug, I see that the desired value is written to context, but on the dropdownlist form, "Reply to" remains empty.

Comment: You're welcome. _it is updated only once when..._ That is normal, when you do not use JS that logic works just once but correctly. JS is not my strong suit, but I guess it needs more work and customization in relation to the admin template, especially if you get the value from FE... . good luck

Comment: Oh, I get it. It's in JS. I should keep digging. Thanks again.